# Запятая перед И в сложносочинённом предложении

Tags: союзы, ссп, и

**О правилах уличного движения, и как мы их соблюдаем.**

Нужна ли здесь запятая перед союзом "и"?

Comment: А не хотите, чтобы не мучиться, сделать так: **"О правилах уличного движения и о том, как мы их соблюдаем"**?

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна, неповторяющийся союз И при однородных членах.

Comment: Хотелось бы поподробней. Каков состав этого предложения?

Comment: Так Наталья уже прояснила состав, я ей класс поставила, понятно же пропущенное О ТОМ. Видимо, это заголовок.  Разговорная, даже просторечная конструкция, когда при пропуске указательного слова придаточное предложение замещает роль однородного члена.